# AngularJS karma filter unknown provider

Tags: angularjs, jasmine, karma-runner, angularjs-filter, karma-jasmine

I can't make it work! I just looked all over the Internet, and I tried other solutions, but I can't make it work.

I got a filter, and I want to test with Karma and Jasmine. Here is my code:

#### app.js:

```
var services = angular.module('myApp.services', [ 'ngResource' ]);

angular.module('myApp', [
    'ngRoute',
    'myApp.filters',
    'myApp.services',
    'myApp.directives',
    'myApp.controllers'
]).
```

#### filters.js

```
'use strict';

/* Filters */

angular.module('myApp.filters', [])

.filter(
    'lowerAndCapital',
    [ function() {
        return function(text) {
            if (text != undefined) {
                var str = text.toLowerCase();
                var arreglo = str.split(" ");
                var result = "";
                for (var i = 0; i < arreglo.length; i++) {
                    result += " "
                            + arreglo[i].charAt(0).toUpperCase()
                            + arreglo[i]
                                    .substring(1, arreglo[i].length + 1);
                }
                return result;
            }
        }
    }]);
```

#### filterSpecs.js

```
'use strict';

/* Jasmine specification for filters go here */

describe('filter', function() {

    beforeEach(function () {
        module('myApp.filters');
    });

    describe('lowerAndCapital', function() {
        it('deberia de convertir le texto a minuscula y con letra capital',
            inject(function(lowerAndCapital) {
                expect(lowerAndCapital("john")).toEqual(
                         "John");
        }));
    });
});
```

#### karma.config.js

```
module.exports = function(config){
    config.set({

        basePath : '../',

        files : [
            'main/webapp/resources/scripts/angular/angular.js',
            'main/webapp/resources/scripts/angular/angular-route.js',
            'main/webapp/resources/scripts/angular/angular-mocks.js',
            'main/webapp/resources/js/*.js',
            'test/unit/*.js'
        ],

        autoWatch : true,

        frameworks: ['jasmine'],

        browsers : ['Chrome'],

        plugins : [
                'karma-chrome-launcher',
                'karma-firefox-launcher',
                'karma-jasmine',
                'karma-junit-reporter'
                ],

        junitReporter : {
          outputFile: 'test_out/unit.xml',
          suite: 'unit'
        }
    });
};
```

And here is the error:

```
Chrome 36.0.1985 (Windows 7) filter lowerAndCapital deberia de convertir le text
o a minuscula y con letra capital FAILED
        Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: lowerAndCapitalProvider <- low
erAndCapital
        http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.16/$injector/unpr?p0=lowerAndCapitalProv
ider%20%3C-%20lowerAndCapital
            at E:/workspace/GPS/src/main/webapp/resources/scripts/angular/angula
r.js:78:12
            at E:/workspace/GPS/src/main/webapp/resources/scripts/angular/angula
r.js:3705:19
            at Object.getService [as get] (E:/workspace/GPS/src/main/webapp/reso
urces/scripts/angular/angular.js:3832:39)
            at E:/workspace/GPS/src/main/webapp/resources/scripts/angular/angula
r.js:3710:45
            at getService (E:/workspace/GPS/src/main/webapp/resources/scripts/an
gular/angular.js:3832:39)
            at Object.invoke (E:/workspace/GPS/src/main/webapp/resources/scripts
/angular/angular.js:3859:13)
            at workFn (E:/workspace/GPS/src/main/webapp/resources/scripts/angula
r/angular-mocks.js:2147:20)
        Error: Declaration Location
            at window.inject.angular.mock.inject (E:/workspace/GPS/src/main/weba
pp/resources/scripts/angular/angular-mocks.js:2132:25)
            at null.<anonymous> (E:/workspace/GPS/src/test/unit/filtersSpec.js:1
5:5)
            at null.<anonymous> (E:/workspace/GPS/src/test/unit/filtersSpec.js:1
2:2)
            at E:/workspace/GPS/src/test/unit/filtersSpec.js:5:1
Chrome 36.0.1985 (Windows 7): Executed 1 of 1 (1 FAILED) ERROR (0.359 secs / 0.0
14 secs)
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You should probably try inject [filterprovider](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/provider/$filterProvider) and get `lowerAndCapital` filter.

```
var $filter;

beforeEach(function () {
   module('app');
});

beforeEach( inject(function (_$filter_) { //<-- Get the filter provider
   $filter = _$filter_;
}));

it('deberia de convertir le texto a minuscula y con letra capital',function(){
   expect($filter('lowerAndCapital')("john")).toEqual("John");
});
```

**[Plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/yhupvW?p=preview)**

Or Postfix your filtername with "Filter" and use it

```
beforeEach( inject(function (_lowerAndCapitalFilter_) {
   $filter = _lowerAndCapitalFilter_;
}));
```

> Filters are just functions which transform input to an output. However filters need to be Dependency Injected. To achieve this a filter definition consists of a factory function which is annotated with dependencies and is responsible for creating a filter function.

But there is a bug in your code because of `split(" ")` so you may want to trim the result returned.

**[Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/SkgSxp?p=preview)**

Comment: Thanks for your answer, is perfect!!! and now i understand that i need to inject the filter provider, just one question? why do you use "_" notation on the filter proivder? thank you so much!

Comment: @user3299573 You are welcome. Yes You don't have to. But while writing unit tests we will mostly have the variable names same as that of the service or provider etc.. So if we inject with the same name, the variable in the upper scope with the same name will not get assigned, so this is another way to inject by providing and "_" as pre/post fix. Nothing much.. As i mentioned you can also postfix your filter with "Filter" and use it as well.

Comment: can i ask you something else? i can understand the demo you provide me, but when im trying to use it with my code when im adding the `beforeEach(module('myApp.filters'));` , karma says that he can't find that module, but in my `app.js` and `filter.js` i got it with the same name, and i don´t know a good way to debug karma, sorry for my inappropriate way of asking hahaha

Comment: Forgetting to postfix the filter name with `Filter` drove me nuts trying to solve no provider error. Thank you so much!